# How to retrieve data and display in the textarea of view after Search the data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. 
I would like to create a module that after search the id, than it will retrieve data from the database and display the data in the textarea. 
I have no idea that how to retrieve data from database, and display the data in the textarea after click the 'Search' button.
Hope someone can help me. Thank You.

This is the Model:

```
function search($code){
   $this->db->select('name','telno','address','introducer');
   $this->db->from('customer');
   $this->db->like('code',$code);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
   }else{
    return $query->result();
   }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
public function searchcus(){ 
    $this->load->model('Ordering_model');
    $pgcode = $this->input->post('search');
    if(isset($code) && !empty($code)){
        $data['customer'] = $this->Ordering_model->search($code);
        $this->load->view('ordering/index',$data);
    }else{
        redirect($this->index());
    }
}
```

This is the View:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo "Customer's PG Code";?> " required />
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"><?php echo "Search"; ?></span></button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </form><br/>
    </div>
    <table style="width: 2000px;" class="table table-striped">
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Tel</span>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" >
                </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Introducer</span>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" >
                </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Address</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="address"></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>


    </table>
```

Comment: you will do this by ajax implementation by call input ```onkeypress``` function on search input field
for more.. please follow this tutorial ```https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_eRdrKCPWY```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code. It works...

Controller:

```
 public function searchcus() {
        $pgcode = $this->input->post('search');
        if (isset($pgcode) && !empty($pgcode)) {
            $data['customerr'] = $this->Ordering_model->search($pgcode);
            $this->load->view('viewpage', $data);
        } else {
            redirect($this->index());
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
   function search($pgcode) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('customer');
        $this->db->like('code',$pgcode);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

View page:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/searchcus">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo "Customer's PG Code";?> " required />
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"><?php echo "Search"; ?></span></button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </form><br/>
    </div>
<?php if(empty($customerr)) { } else { foreach($customerr as $row) { ?>
    <table style="width: 2000px;" class="table table-striped">
                 <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" value="<?php echo $row->name ?>" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Tel</span>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" value="<?php echo $row->telno ?>" >
                </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Introducer</span>
                    <input id="msg" type="text" class="form-control" name="msg" value="<?php echo $row->introducer ?>" >
                </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Address</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="address"> <?php echo $row->address ?></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>


    </table>
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to Use Model Code for searching :

if ($code && $code != '') {
            $where = "(TABLE_NAME.COLUMN LIKE '%" . $code . "%')";
        }

Answer (score 0):

with the ajax you can achive your goal here is the some changes
**Model :**

```
function search($code){
   $this->db->select('name','telno','address','introducer');
   $this->db->from('customer');
   $this->db->like('code',$code);// by default it will run '%$code%' no change here
   $query = $this->db->get();
   if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
   }else{
        return array();
   }
}
```

**Controller :**

```
public function searchcus(){ 
    $this->load->model('Ordering_model');
    $code = $this->input->post('search');//changes
    if(!empty($code)){//changes
        $data['customer'] = $this->Ordering_model->search($code);
        $this->load->view('ordering/index',$data);
    }else{
        redirect($this->index());
    }
}
```